# Could not build application for the simulator for flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have done every thing and changed the iOS version to 10 in the pod file but it is still getting the error.

```
base) Gopis-MacBook-Pro:studyhall gopichand$ flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
 
Running pod install...                                              8.4s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         5.0s
Xcode build done.                                           16.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

Xcode's output:

```
↳
    /Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-akyazhjaclkrdsdykcdxdgdzdeof/Build/Intermediates
    .noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-FD4D52F9DFAD0D40F508D02D.sh: line 2:
    /Users/gopichand/Desktop/studyhall/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh:
    Permission denied
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'fluttertoast' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseFirestore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'firebase_core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'cloud_firestore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'firebase_auth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuthInterop' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error can occur due to multiple reasons.

- Firstly, it can occur due to some native error which can be found by building the app in Xcode using `⌘ + B`. If that's the case then you can solve the error and try building the app in the Xcode itself. If it succeeds in the building process then your app will run from Simulator.
- Secondly, try to change the iOS version from Xcode if not done already.
- Thirdly, it can occur due to some changes in the pods. To fix this follow the following steps:

  - `rm ios/Podfile`
  - `flutter pub get` to get packages.
  - Remove **Pods** folder from the ios folder in the directory.
  - `cd ios` then `pod install`
  - `flutter clean`
  - Run the project. ( Press `F5` if you are using VSCode )

I hope this solves your issue.